# How do I prove that $3x^3 +2x + 1 $ is $\omega(x \cdot \log x) $

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics, proof-techniques, complexity-classes, landau-notation

I am trying to answer this question:
$3x^3 +2x + 1$ is $ \omega(x \cdot \log x)$

My question is how to solve this question.

Here is what I have tried so far:

I applied the definition $3x^3 + 2x + 1 > c \cdot x\log x$ for all c, given $n \geq k$, for some k

I tried to apply the technique of applying the equality that:
$n < n^3$

Since n is less than the highest order term we can just move all terms to order n ??

Giving $6x < c \cdot x \log x$

Then you can choose:
$k < 2^\frac{6}{c}$

Comment: You seem to be confusing $\omega$ and $o$.

Comment: Thanks Yuval, I made the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I recommend first is to notice that if you're looking at the **complexity** of the function $3x^2+2x+1$, really all you should care about is the function $x^2$.
because **if** you will prove that $x^2 = \omega(xlogx)$
then adding the $2x + 1$ won't ruin that proof since $x^2$ is polynomially bigger than $2x + 1$ and so we can just look at the $x^2$.

(I will use $n$ instead of $x$ because that is what I'm familiar with but it's exactly the same for $x$)

So now what we want to prove is that $$n^2 = \omega(nlogn)$$

which as you offered only you need to flip your sides in the equation, we will need to find a positive $C$, so that for any $n>n_0$ or $n>k$ :
$$f(n)\ge C\cdot g(n)$$
when 
$f(n) = n^2$ , $g(n) = nlogn$

That will get us to:
$n^2 \ge Cnlogn $

We can divide both side by $n$:
$$n \ge Clogn$$

Now that's a bit of a tricky one.
but "it is known" that polynomial running time is SLOWER than logarithmic one.

Basically what that means is that you'd prefer to reach a logarithmic complexity running time if possible because than you'll get faster execution.

Generally this is the order of running times when the first is the fastest:

$$1.Constant$$
$$2.Logarithmic$$
$$3.Linear$$
$$4.Linearithmic$$
$$5.Polynomial$$
$$6.Exponential$$

(you can read more about it here: https://adrianmejia.com/most-popular-algorithms-time-complexity-every-programmer-should-know-free-online-tutorial-course/)

Another way to see it is if you'll  find the limit of the division of the two functions, let's say we'll choose:
$${f(n) \over g(n)}$$

If $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {f(n) \over g(n)} \rightarrow \infty$$
It means that $f(n)$ is "much bigger" than $g(n)$

If $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {f(n) \over g(n)} \rightarrow 0$$
It means that $f(n)$ is "much smaller" than $g(n)$

The last option (Atleast in this method) is:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {f(n) \over g(n)} \rightarrow C$$
When $C \gt 0$ which means both of the functions have Asymptotically the same complexity.

Back to our functions, we can see that :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {n \over log(n)}$$

We will use lupital rule and get:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {1 \over 1/n} \rightarrow \infty$$

We now can see that $f(n) = n$ is bigger Asymptotically from $g(n) = log(n)$ hence :
$$n = \omega (log(n))$$

---

I really hope I explained as clear and easy as possible, it's just English isn't my mother tongue language so I apolegize in advance for any mistakes with grammer etc.

---

Update : I've noticed you've made changes to the original function and now it is $3x^3+2x+1$, yet the proof will be the same, just use $n^3$ and than you'll still get the same result when using lupital. 
That because, inevitably, if we just proved that $n^2$ is much bigger than $log(n)$ than of course that $n^3$ which is much bigger than $n^2$ would also be bigger than $log(n).$

Comment: This answered my question because he explained the three different classifications from the limit function unlike the answer below. I prefer the second method because it seems to follow a more formal approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to check that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x^3 + 2x +1}{ x \log x} = +\infty$, which is a sufficient condition for $3x^3 + 2x +1 \in \omega(x \log x)$.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x^3 + 2x +1}{ x \log x} =
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x^3}{ x \log x} = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{3x^2}{  \log x} =
\lim_{x \to \infty}  6x^2 
= +\infty.
$$

Comment: I don't understand how that is a sufficient condition ? So we don't have to find witness pairs?

Comment: Assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions that are eventually positive. By definition of limit, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is $+\infty$ if $\forall c\,  \exists n_0 \, \forall n> n_0, \, \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \ge c$. This implies that $\forall c>0 \, \exists n_0 \, \forall n> n_0, \, f(x) \ge c g(x)$, i.e., that $f(x) = \omega(g(x))$. In this way you have shown that, for all $c>0$, there must be some value of $n_0$ (that depends on $c$) that satisfies the definition of $\omega(\cdot)$ without bothering to explicitly compute such $n_0$.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123897/algorithms-determining-asymptotic-notation-from-a-given-execution-time/123908#123908).