# Time Complexity of given functions

Tags: time-complexity

What is if we have

```
f(n) = 15n^2logn  +500n^2,5 ,
 g(n) = n^3 + 1000 , 
h(n) = 21n^3logn , 
x(n) = 50n^2,5 +  n*log(n)
```

How to check   " is `f(n) O(g(n)  or O(h(n)) , or O(x(n)) and why?`  and other examples?
like `is h(n) O(g(n)) or is f(n) O(n^2logn)`

Comment: An easy way that works for most "nice" positive functions is that of evaluating the limit of the ratio of the two functions you are interested in as $n$ approaches $+\infty$. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ exists and is finite then $f(n) = O(g(n))$. The converse is not true. This method works for all pairs of the above functions.

Comment: could be more specific?  ok we will use DLH on the limit but what the  result must to be ? could you provide me an example? thank you in advance

Comment: See [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123897/algorithms-determining-asymptotic-notation-from-a-given-execution-time/123908#123908), which also contains an example.

Comment: @Steven Okay thank you. One last question.  Lets stay  on f(n) . Is it correct that 
500n^2,5 > 15^2logn so to the lim f(n) we can take n^2,5 only?